# Get current date and time of "Pacific/Noumea" timezone in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

How to get current date and time of "Pacific/Noumea" timezone using PHP.

I have try bellow code but not working properly.

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Pacific/Noumea');
$today = time();
echo date("d/m/Y h:i:s a", $today);
```

Comment: Its working perfect for me. here is output
03/01/2018 09:22:36 pm

Comment: for me some gap of time : 03/01/2018 09:44:14 pm

Comment: How is it failing? What result where you expecting and what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your time zone than use **date_default_timezone_set('your_time_zone');**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Noumea');
echo $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to define timezone for your application:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Noumea");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to set time zone globally for running script you may use the following snippet

```
<?php
  $date = new \DateTime('now',  new \DateTimeZone('Pacific/Noumea'));
  echo $date->format('d/m/Y h:i:s a');
?>
```